# How can I dynamically change the 'wrap' property of an iCarousel object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, coverflow, icarousel

I am using the iCarousel library that Nick Lockwood has very generously provided on github.  It is very well done and I appreciate the high level of abstraction.

During user tests, some users have been confused by the cover flow wrapping on our application.  I suppose this is inconsistent with the 'native' use in the music app.  Personally, for our use, I think it helps quite a bit.

Our 'solution' was to leave this up the user by provided an option in the settings menu to wrap the cover flow.  I expected that iCarousel would call the delegate whenever the view became active, which would then check the user settings for their preference.

Unfortunately I am finding that not to be the case.

Is there a way to 'refresh' this parameter without reloading the entire view?

Comment: I do realize that I can [carousel reloadData], just wondered if there was another way when you only changed a single parameter like 'wrap'

Comment: I think it's important to note that calling -reloadData is the expected and proper way to do this. It's not a hack or a workaround. When objects associated with the carousel change, you should always call -reloadData (that is if the underlying data changes or if you make changes to the carousel). Because of this, you should program the iCarouselDataSource delegate methods to be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do it without calling reloadData because the carousel may display a different set of views when wrap is enabled.

Calling reloadData should be invisible to the user anyway, so I don't see a problem with calling it.